Planar transformer core power handling
I have come to a point where I’m required to design a planar transformer, nevertheless that’s honestly the first time I’m designing any magnetics and I have thus very little experience.
The output power in my application has to be something below 3 kW - this range is open for lower values, so 1 kW for example would also be good. This would be a centre-tapped transformer with two diodes and a resistive load, so the power rating of the transformer should be something around 1.75xPout.
My question is: how can one evaluate how much power can a planar transformer core handling?
For example, let’s take this planar core: https://feryster.pl/assets/nowa/pdf/e641050.pdf - given the data from this sheet, is there an easy way to evaluate the power it can handle?
I found the information that for three-column transformer core the power handling can be evaluated by its size. What’s the deal with planar cores?
The target frequency is 750 kHz.

For any switch-mode technology except for flyback, the core limitation will be losses. What’s yours? How are you cooling the product?

kazap - Hi, You posted an "answer", but it was really part of the question. Therefore it should not have been posted in the "Your Answer" box & it has been moved into the question as an edit i.e. as an update instead. || Unless you are writing the full & final solution to your own question, different from any other answers (i.e. you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please don't use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead, you should [edit] the question to add new information or clarification etc. (unless that would invalidate existing answers, if any). TY

Some devices can handle 100s of kW for short periods of time but only watts continuously. You need to be clear about what you mean. It would also help immensely if you divulged your transformer design so that any answer can focus effectively instead of receiving a load of follow-up questions.

Complete component design includes electromagnetic and thermal design aspects.
The datasheet gives you some hints on thermal:

For typical materials,
In suggested test conditions,
...Expected power dissipation.

They also give typical / stocked / suggested air gap values, in case you might be using the core for an inductor, flyback transformer, or resonant (e.g. LLC) converter.
For example, they show "E+E64-3C94" at under 25W, at 100kHz 200mT 100°C.  That's pretty high flux density, close to saturation, so it's no accident the power level is pretty high.  For something 50 x 64 mm, you almost certainly need a heatsink to handle that kind of power.  Let alone what power the windings dissipate.
The same flux density at 750kHz, absolutely needs a heatsink, and would very much call into question the thermal conductivity of the ferrite itself: it's not very high, it's a fairly middling ceramic as things go, glass-hard but not quite as strong, and certainly not as conductive as alumina (a common insulating ceramic used for resistor substrates, heatsinking, etc.), let alone a metal.  Thus, the peak core temperature, in the middle of the transformer, even with the outer faces cooled to 25°C, might heat up so much that it becomes inoperable (exceeds TC) or damages itself (too much thermal strain).
So, clearly we can't read everything from the tables, and further information is required.
Notice that a core does not transform power, per se.  A core dissipates some power, based on applied flux and frequency.  To dissipate power in a flux, some current is required.  The permeability is finite, so there will be nonzero magnetizing current through the primary winding, the phase angle of which will normally be inductive, but a resistive component is also present, and this gives the core loss.  (This would imply high permeability can be used to "cheat" low loss, but as it turns out, such ferrites have a lower cutoff frequency, and higher eddy currents; that is, the phase angle of magnetizing current is closer to resistive.  The best ferrites only go up to 10, 15, 20k μr anyway, far from infinity -- TANSTAAFL.)
A transformer couples current between windings, a current in superposition with the magnetizing current and thus independent of it (at least to first order; there is a reduction effect due to leakage, but leakage itself may touch the core in subtle ways).  This current only flows between the windings themselves; if we had superconducting windings, we might transmit -- well, not infinite, even superconductors have their limits -- but to say very high power anyway, by cranking up the current.  (Again, AC voltage is fixed by core flux, but current would be a nearly free variable that way.)
But we don't have superconductors, we have ordinary metals, like copper, so clearly that resistivity will be a factor in our design, and of what power we are able to dissipate from it.  Not to mention, of how much we can put into the winding area -- planar designs, built with traditional planar fabrication methods (PCBs), provide a rather low fraction (winding factor) of copper, which further affects our design.  (It's no accident that planar cores have a relatively large winding window, compared to traditional bobbin types; E, PQ, RM, etc..)
At this point -- stopping short of actual equations, or rather, leaving them as an exercise for the student -- they are simple products and ratios so far -- we can do basic design: taking the current, turns ratio, frequency and given core, and solving for turns and power dissipation.  (Along the way, you'll need the mean length of turn (MLT), and the wire (or trace) cross section.)
But so we come back to power.
To get a real number for core loss, we have to refer to the material datasheet.  For example, Ferroxcube 3C90.  Notice Fig.6 gives power vs. flux density for frequency as parameter.  We can fit a generalized Steinmetz curve to this, \$p = c f^\alpha B^\beta\$ (where core loss \$P = p v_e\$), which is only an approximation mind -- and the real figure in practice depends on core geometry and frequency, in a more complex manner than these curves give (the manufacturer measures them on one standard core; the cross section, aspect ratio and length all differ between shapes, while the field distribution depends on geometry), but we don't usually need to know losses this accurately so a 10 or 20% error is acceptable for engineering purposes.
Ultimately, the best accuracy is what you measure; highly accurate modeling is just not available (or at least, not from datasheet parameters).
We can make assumptions about power dissipation, like a surface convection rate (average shapes in still air give ballpark 1000 cm2 °C/W; divide by surface area to get thermal resistance), but then we need the surface area, and that scales inconsistently between core shapes, sizes, and how we arrange the thing.  The winding has some open area (at the ends of the core, outside it, where the turns turn back) as well, and we need to estimate that.
The transformer might be embedded in a PCB, which we need to know the lateral heat spreading of, or the whole thing might be conduction cooled (gap pads, spreaders, heatsinks) and we need to know the conductivity of everything, and some basic geometry to get it back into units of thermal resistance.  But not just thermal resistance across the assembly, but specifically to the worst-case (hot spot) temperature within it, which isn't going to be easy to determine.
So it tends to be that, we tentatively evaluate several plausible core sizes, and do further checking to see if they'd get ballpark too much temp rise to test or model, and then go iteratively from there.

I'm keeping this answer fairly vague and high-level, as a complete and direct answer simply won't fit in this margin (I know, I've tried on another subject--), and whole books have been written on the topic.  Not to mention, I'm hardly an extensive authority myself: I've done several fairly in-depth designs, but that's quite far from having seen every possible configuration and rating.  Put another way, this is something of a non-answer answer, as I don't intend to answer your direct question, but to give surrounding information to guide your thought process on the subject.
To that end, for a more complete, book-level answer, you may find this reference useful: 
Erickson and Maksimovic, Fundamentals of Power Electronics, Springer 
Any edition/printing should do.  They go into much more detail, top to bottom through the subject, including details such as how to optimize inductor and transformer design.
